# Default wait-time in loadrunner winsock protocol

Tags: time, wait, winsock, loadrunner

By default, loadrunner - Winsock protocol waits for 10 secs to read\compare the received buffer.

Is it possible to reduce this wait time to less...around 1 second?

Thanks
Anna

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see following functions in help for potential insight to your issue

if you are having trouble with a valid, but mismatched buffer, then take a look at what the following function can do for you behaviorally on the system

```
lrs_set_send_buffer()
```

If, on the other hand, you are looking for generic timeout functions, take a look at the following.  These are also available in the product documentation/function reference under Winsock/Timeout functions

```
lrs_set_accept_timeout()
lrs_set_connect_timeout()
lrs_set_recv_timeout()
lrs_set_recv_timeout2()
lrs_set_send_timeout()
```

Comment: Thanks James. I was trying to eliminate the built-in wait time of 10 seconds that is used to read\compare the buffer. I tried lrs_set_recv_timeout2() and was able to remove the waster time in buffer comparison.

Comment: Can you please explain the difference between lrs_set_recv_timeout() and lrs_set_recv_timeout2(). in my current test scenario, i have to test a basic send and receive TCP connection.But i need to make sure the required TPS is received from the test machines.

Comment: Without lrs_set_recv_timeout2() option, by default the script waits for 10 seconds for buffer read and comparison. In the test script, i have set lrs_set_recv_timeout() to 42 seconds, since that is the application timeout value and have set lrs_set_recv_timeout2() to 1 second. Does that mean the transaction will fail if the response time exceeds 1 second. I am trying to understand how lrs_set_recv_timeout() and lrs_set_recv_timeout2() works if used together.

Comment: See the use and the benefits of lrs_set_send_buffer() for how long the system waits for a matched response buffer.

Comment: Thanks James. I was able to limit the wait time (buffer comparison time) by using lrs_set_recv_timeout2()

Comment: lr_set_recv_timeout() is the timeout given in the client for the server to process the message, send the response and for the first byte of the response to be received by the client. lr_set_recv_timout2() is the timeout given in the client for receiving the whole response after the first byte of the response has arrived. Hope this is clear.